# tableview not so responsive

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, asynchronous

My app is too slow in responding, I guess I'm not loading images Asynchronously, but even if I do still then the tableview makes my controller load too slow. The code for tableview is below:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    UILabel *productNameLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(83, 8, 200,10)];
        [productNameLbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0]];
        [productNameLbl setTag:20];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:productNameLbl];
        [productNameLbl release];


}

else {
    AsyncImageView *oldImage = (AsyncImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:299];
    [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
}


NSString *baseImageURL = @"http://samplesite.com/";

AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 70, 70)] autorelease];
asyncImage.tag = 299;
NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString *iconUrl = [NSString stringWithString:[[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] categoryProducts ] productsList ]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productImage]];

[url appendString:baseImageURL];
[url appendString:iconUrl];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
[asyncImage loadImageFromURL:imageURL];
[cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];

[(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:20] setText:[NSString stringWithString:[[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] categoryProducts ] productsList ]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productName]]];
//..... rest of the code
```

What I actually want is, to load the view first and then can load the images and rest of the data.
Please, tell me how can I make my tableview more responsive.

Comment: Good formatting is your friend!

Comment: You are leaking an imageview

     [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightstrip.png"]]];

This should be:
     [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightstrip.png"] autorelease]]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was much easier and really solved the problem :)
http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~wayne/yellowjacket/YellowJacket.zip

Answer (score 2):

You are createing all the Label every time the cell gets displayed. 
You should either add tag to all the label and locate them via the tag. So not to create them.

Or better create a custom tabelCell with all the controls you need.

You can laod the image async in the UITableViewDelegate methods willDisplayCell:AtIndex: then check some kind of local cache if the images has already been downloaded.
Have a look at ASIHttpRequest which has a great caching system which is real easy to use.

Comment: I've already used asynchronous calls for the images. But still the controller is very slow. How can I show the view first and then load it ??? I mean navigating from root controller to view controller, as of now it loads the data first and then displays the view. I just want to reverse the process, display the view first and then load the data. Please tell me how can I do that ???

Answer (score 1):

If you make this whole part of your code aysnc, your code would be very smooth (mind your leaks + allocations though).

```
NSMutableString *url = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString *baseImageURL = @"http://samplesite.com/";
NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithString:[[[[DataCollection sharedObject] popularProducts]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] productImage]];

[url appendString:baseImageURL];
[url appendString:imagePath];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 70, 70)];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Comment: I already made it Async, but I'm still wondering how to display the controller first and then load the data. Any help, please ???

Comment: I used this library 
https://github.com/hugowetterberg/HBaseLibrary/blob/master/README.markdown 

 , but now it's showing me another error :

Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AsyncImageLoader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-AsyncImageLoader in AsyncImageView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
I've not added the whole library in my project, instead I copied only the selected files and their reference files too. Please tell me how can I remove this error ???

Comment: You are obviously under the impression that the code you shared is async. All I am saying is that it isn't. The only way you can solve this is by subclassing the cell (well, not the only way) and do an async NSURL request there and set the image once the request is complete. That is async. This is just blocking the main thread, and thus making your table behave the way it does..

Comment: I'm really sorry for not updating the post, I've updated it now with the latest modifications i did. Please, have a look and tell me how can I remove the error, which I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) project that deals with this issue specifically. Perhaps this model can help you out.